# Собрать только libclang

Tags: clang

Какие опции нужно указать, чтобы собрать только библиотеку libclang и нужные ей библиотеки? Нужен функционал предоставляемый только этой библиотекой, все остальное и сам clang не нужен. ОС Windows, Linux

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! вряд ли вас интересует буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) так, чтобы на него можно было дать полноценный ответ

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован вполне чётко. Единственное, чего не хватает, это не указана операционная система. Mac OS, Linux?

Comment: Добавил указание ОС